# Excel: Find All Instances of Text Strings in Range and Return Each Instance

Tags: string, excel, vba, find, formula

I need to find all instances of particular identifier that may occur in one column and concatenate them into one string.

The identifier will start with `"ECP"` and be separated by a dash or space and have several characters after the separator. E.g. `"ECP 05-00012A1, "ECP-123456."`

I was using the formula below, but didn't think of multiple "ECP numbers."

`=INDEX('Raw WAM Data'!$A$1:$A$10000,MATCH(VLOOKUP("*"&"ECP"&"*",'Raw WAM Data'!$A$1:$A$10000,1,FALSE),'Raw WAM Data'!$A$1:$A$10000,0))`

I was then parsing the data in an adjacent cell using: `=LEFT($C$62,FIND(" ", $C$62, FIND(" ", $C$62)+1))`
This string was then loaded into a UserForm TextBox.

I would then need concatenate all the returned values into one string separated by commas so that it can load into the UserForm TextBox.

I would think that VBA would be ideal for this, but I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: You could use an array and join in VBA.  Are you happy with your extraction of the data, it's unclear what you want, the extraction of data, or how to concatenate effectivelyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got correct understanding of what you trying to achive then you can use something like this:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cl As Range, x&
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace sheet1 by name of your sheet
        x = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cl In .Range(.[A1], .Cells(x, "A"))
            If UCase(cl.Value2) Like "ECP*" And Not dic.exists(cl.Value2) Then
                dic.Add cl.Value2, Nothing
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
    Debug.Print Join(dic.keys, Chr(10))
End Sub
```

*test*

[image]

---

**Updated**

> What's the best way to put the results in Column E relative to the cell in which it was found? Also, if I wanted to search multiple columns, how should I adapt the code?

you can use this way:

```
Sub TEST2()
    Dim cl As Range, x&
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace sheet1 by name of your sheet
        x = .[A:C].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row 'get the last used row in range
        For Each cl In .Range(.[A1], .Cells(x, "C"))
            If UCase(cl.Value2) Like "*ECP*" Then
                If .Cells(cl.Row, "E").Value2 = "" Then
                    .Cells(cl.Row, "E").Value2 = cl.Value2
                Else
                    .Cells(cl.Row, "E").Value2 = .Cells(cl.Row, "E").Value2 & "; " & cl.Value2
                End If
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

*Output*

[image]

Comment: I ran this code, but nothing happened. I didn't get any errors either.

Comment: this code does printing of the result to `immediate window`, use `Ctrl + G` to activate this window. See the data sample `marked by red` in screenshot and output result also `marked by red`. The posted code is works fine, and output goes to `immediate window` because you haven't specified where output result should goes (e.g. to new sheet, or to some column of existing sheet and so on).

Comment: Still nothing and I know there are "ECP" values in the range.

Comment: As I already mentioned, the code works fine, and you can see the data sample and output result in screenshot. The logic behind the code is simple, 1) if cell value starts from `"ECP"` - add cell value to the dictionary, 2) print all items that have been added to dictionary. I guess that you need to search not only values that start from `"ECP"` but also values that **contain `"ECP"`**, to do that you need to add additional preceded asteriks to criteria for comparing **`"*ECP*"`** (e.g. **`If UCase(cl.Value2) Like "*ECP*"`**). I hope this will help)

Comment: Bingo, that worked. What's the best way to put the results in Column E relative to the cell in which it was found? Also, if I wanted to search multiple columns, how should I adapt the code?

Comment: Thanks @Vasily! The entire string in which the ECP values were found ended up being copied over, but I was able to manually remove the information I didnt need.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in column A of a worksheet this routine will gather your ECP numbers and load them into an array. You can then load the array into your TextBox.

```
Sub GatherECPs()

Dim ECParr

'Loop down each row starting at row 2 (assuming you have headers)
For x = 2 To SourceSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    'Check if the start of the string is ECP
    If Left(SourceSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, 3) = "ECP" Then
        'Add a row to the array
        If IsEmpty(ECParr) Then
            ReDim ECParr(0)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve ECParr(UBound(ECParr) + 1)
        End If
        'Add the value to the array
        ECParr(UBound(ECParr)) = Right(SourceSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, Len(SourceSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value) - 4)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Replace SourceSheet with the sheet where your values exist.

Comment: If I `Debug.Print ECParr` I do not see any results

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a fast way which also works for multiple "ECP" in one cell just use this function:

```
Public Function getStr(rng As Range, ident As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, x As Variant, y As Variant
  For Each x In Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value
    y = Split(x, ident)
    If UBound(y) > 0 Then
      For i = 1 To UBound(y)
        getStr = getStr & ", " & ident & Split(y(i), ",")(0)
      Next
    End If
  Next
  getStr = Mid(getStr, 3)
End Function
```

It will return a comma separated string. just use it like: `getStr(Range("A:A"), "ECP")`

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: What's the best way to pass the result to a certain column (column E) of the same row in which the value was found?

Comment: As UDF you could put in E1 `=getStr(A1,"ECP")` and then copy down. Should do it like you want it...